Show that for $(u_{n})$ strictly decreasing sequence tending to 0, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{u_{n}-u_{n+1}}{u_{n+1}}$ diverges
I come to ask you about a problem coming from a serie's exercice sheet brought by a student that I can't crack.
Let $(u_{n})$ be a strictly positive decreasing sequence which converges to 0.
How do I prove that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{u_{n}-u_{n+1}}{u_{n+1}} \textrm{ diverges ?}$$
Having no other information on $(u_n)$, I've tried many ways (ratio test, partial sum increasing...) but I always end up trying to show that
$$ \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} > \frac{u_{n+2}}{u_{n+1}} \textrm{ which I can't really prove}$$
Any lead ?

For $0 \le p \le n \le q$ is $u_{n+1} \le u_p$ and therefore
$$
 \sum_{n=p}^q \frac{u_{n}-u_{n+1}}{u_{n+1}} \ge 
\sum_{n=p}^q \frac{u_{n}-u_{n+1}}{u_{p}}
= \frac{1}{u_p}\sum_{n=p}^q (u_{n}-u_{n+1}) \\
= \frac{1}{u_p} (u_p - u_{q+1}) = 1 - \frac{u_{q+1}}{u_p} \, .
$$
But $(u_n)$ converges to zero, so this shows that the series is divergent by Cauchy's convergence test: For all $p \ge 0$ exists a $q > p$ such that the right-hand side is $> 1/2$.

I dont quite understand the last part : how does the fact that $(u_{n})$ converges to $0$ proves that the right-hand side is $> \frac{1}{2}$ ? Is it because it respects Cauch'ys convergence's test  ?

@ArmandJourdain: For fixed $p$  and $q \to \infty $ converges $1 - \frac{u_{q+1}}{u_p}$ to $1 - 0 = 1$, so that it is $> 1/2$ for sufficiently large $q$.

Ok I see it, thanks !

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u_n-u_{n+1}}{u_{n+1}}\ge \int_{0}^{u_0}\frac{dx}{x}=+\infty$$
Because over the interval $[u_{n+1}, u_n]$, $\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}\ge\frac{1}{x}$, so the sum dominates the integral.

I was about to write a remark about the upper bound of the integral, but you already fixed that :) – Nice argument!

Suppose the conlusion fails. Then $\frac {u_{n}}{u_{n+1}} \to 1$. Consider the infinite product $\prod \frac {u_{n+1}}{u_n}$. Since $\sum [1-\frac {u_{n+1}}{u_n}]=\sum \frac {u_n-u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\sum \frac {u_n-u_{n+1}}{u_{n+1}}\frac {u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ is convergent, it follows that our infinite product converges. But then (computing the partial products we see that)  $\frac {u_n} {u_{1}}$ converges to a  nonzero number, contradicting the hypothesis.
Ref. for infinite products: Rudin's RCA.

It works quite nicely, I didn't think of infinite product !
